# BindToMoniker Com application

Tags: c#

I have a service running (Indesign server) and would like to use C# BindToMoniker method.

InDesignServer.Application app = (InDesignServer.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(monikerName);

How do I get the moniker name from a program/service?

Answer (score 1):

Moniker name in this case is - configuration name of InDesign Server.

Configuration name is specified when you start the server process, for example:

> InDesignServer.com -configuration myconfig